# Insert TOC at start of document

Tags: hyperref, color, documentclass-writing

I'm trying to insert the ToC and later on the other lists (lot, lof,...) directly after `\begin{document}` using the hook `\AtBeginDocument`. This is working as long as `hyperref` is *not* loaded with `\AtEndPreamble`. This causes the error

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>    \Hy@colorlink
>
> l.1 ...ly duck at level 0 (chapter)}{2}{chapter.1}

How can I insert the ToC at the start of the document when `hyperref` get loaded inside my class?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{setest.cls}
    \ProvidesClass{setest}[2018-07-10 v0.1 SE Testclass]
    \RequirePackage{etoolbox}
    \LoadClass{scrreprt}

    \@ifpackageloaded{xcolor}{}{\RequirePackage{xcolor}}

    % Probably causing the issue
    \AtEndPreamble{%
        \RequirePackage{hyperref}
        \hypersetup{%
            colorlinks,
            allcolors=red,
            urlcolor=blue%
        }%
    }

%    Insert TOC after \begin{document}
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \tableofcontents
    }

    \endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{setest}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{duckuments}
%----
% Working as expected
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%
%\hypersetup{%
%    colorlinks,
%    allcolors=red,
%    urlcolor=blue%
%}%
%
%\AtBeginDocument{%
%    \tableofcontents%
%}
%---

\begin{document}
    \duckument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why end preamble and not just `\AtBeginDocument`? There seems to be a timing issue. Also why force the TOC to be on the first page? Will users always accept that?

Comment: @daleif This class acts like a template with a given document structure. I the real case there will be a titlepage first. So the answer of your second question is yes. Do you mean loading `hyperref` within `\AtBeginDocument`?

Comment: Yes, `hyperref` already it self does stuff at `\BeginDocument`, so my guess is that the sequencing between the stuff `hyperref` needs to do and and the addition of the TOC is wrong.

Comment: Maybe: `\AfterEndPreamble{\tableofcontents}`

Comment: Having toc and hyperref both in AtBeginDocument works fine, no idea why your combination does not work

Comment: @daleif Putting both inside `\AtBeginDocument` is working fine but you can't set `\hypersetup` anymore.
@esdd `\AfterEndPreamble{\tableofcontents}` seems to work perfectly fine. Thanks

Comment: Intertesting, anyways I'd be careful auto loading hyperref anyway. What about a user wanting to use `cleverref`?

Comment: @daleif `cleveref` will be loaded as well. But this didn't caused this issue :) As I sad before the resulting class is suppose to act like a template for a certain type of paper where a user just change some configuration.

Comment: No, but `cleverref` has to be loaded `after` `hyperref` what if the user uses another package that also need to run after hyperref?

Comment: `cleveref` is loaded *after* `hyperref` using `\AfterPackage!{hyperref}`. I really appreciate your concerns but for now the developed class just fits its requirements.

Comment: You have mentioned that you want to do the same for LoF and LoT: If there are no figures and/or tables in the document, then you will get empty LoF and/or LoT ...

Comment: @esdd You are right. I totally forgot this fact so I might come up with another question soon :)

Comment: Hey, I found a similar issue [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653886/chapter-labelsec-make-double-references-in-the-table-of-contents-of-wuhan/653964#653964). Seems like it's a bug with `hyperref` or `etoolbox`, I don't know.