# \chapter{\label{sec: }} make double references in the table of contents of Wuhan University template

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing

I am using the template of Wuhan University. I found that if I do as `\chapter{\label{sec: }}`, the table of contents will show double references. For example,in the `chapter 1.tex` I input

```
\chapter{1}\label{sec:1}
\section{woemn}\label{sec:women}
```

and in the `appendix.tex` I input `\chapter{对应\ref{sec:women}\nameref{sec:women}}`.
In the table of content, there is
[image]

The red part contains duplicated references and the yellow part is redundant. I knew there is a need to make an MWE here, but I can't. So I update the file to Figshare where all the files can't be removed, so others can check these files in the future. After downloading it, unzip the file and run `whu-thesis-demo.tex` with `xelatex->biber->xelatex->xelatex` and you will see this error.
The file is here: [the file](https://figshare.com/articles/software/Duplicated_references/20484165)

Comment: It would be easier if you provided a MWE.  But isn't the point of `\nameref` to print the section name that it references?  What are you trying to do with `nameref`?

Comment: It is beyond my ability to make a MWE. It should be **1.1woemn** not **1.1woemnsection.1.1woemn**. @Teepeemm

Comment: Have you tried changing `\chapter{对应\ref{sec:women}\nameref{sec:women}}` to  `\chapter{对应\protect\ref{sec:women}\protect\nameref{sec:women}}`, followed by a full recompile cycle?

Comment: @Mico I tried, but it is the same.

Comment: `\chapter{对应\ref{sec:women}\nameref{sec:women}}` should be `\chapter[something]{对应\ref{sec:women}\nameref{sec:women}}` (perhaps using `\ref*` in the `something` so it does not make a link) the table of contents text is a link to the section so can not have nested links,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\ref*` is the same. I don't why this template has this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lengthy experimentation, I discovered the problem.

Your issue seems to be due to a bug that occurs when the following conditions hold:

1. A custom class is used. In it,
2. `hyperref` is loaded within `AtEndPreamble`, and
3. `\tableofcontents` is loaded within `AtBeginDocument`.

Here's an MWE that reproduces the problem.

```
\begin{filecontents}{exampleclass.cls}
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
    \ProvidesClass{custom}
    \LoadClass{article}
    \RequirePackage{etoolbox}
    \AtEndPreamble{% APPARENTLY THIS CAUSES THE TROUBLE
        \RequirePackage{hyperref}
        \hypersetup{hidelinks}
        }
    \AtBeginDocument{
        \tableofcontents
    }
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{exampleclass}
\begin{document}
\section{First Section}\label{firstsec}
\section{Second Sectsion: On \ref{firstsec}}
\end{document}
```

This gives the bad ToC:
[image]

The bug is inscrutable. It probably has to do with timing and so on, but how it works is beyond me. I found similar issues posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440041/insert-toc-at-start-of-document) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529385/atendpreamble-hook-breaks-hyperref-with-bibliography). By the way, if you remove the line `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` from the MWE, the file flat out won't compile. Yet the fact that it *does* compile when you throw in this line makes the bug very weird.

### Fix

To fix this issue, you either *don't* put `\tableofcontents` in `AtBeginDocument` or *don't* load `hyperref` in `AtEndPreamble`.

In OP's case, it's easy: go to `whu-thesis.class`: change `\AtBeginDocument` on `line 1024` to `\AfterEndPreamble`.

Another way to fix this is to move `\RequirePackage{hyperref}\hypersetup{hidelinks}` *out of* `\AtEndPreamble`. The relevant code is somewhere around `line 724`. Essentially, make the code look like this:

```
...
...
    \RequirePackage { hyperref }
    \hypersetup { hidelinks }
    \urlstyle { rm }

\AtEndPreamble
  {
    \hypersetup
      {
        pdftitle  = \g__whu_info_title_tl,
        pdfauthor = \g__whu_info_author_tl
      }

    \tl_set_eq:NN \figureautorefname \figurename
    \tl_set_eq:NN \tableautorefname  \tablename
  }
...
...
```

Can't blame OP for not providing an MWE. The file is so damn huge. On the other hand, maybe OP could've simply stopped using `\ref` in headings.

Maybe someone should submit a bug report of some kind.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your way is good. May you tell me what package this bug belongs to?

Comment: Thanks @Y.zeng I think it’s a `hyperref` bug?

Comment: Thanks. But, the bug has been found for over 4 years and the `hyperref` has been updated several times in these 4 years. It is weird that the author of `hyperref` didn't correct it.

Comment: @Y.zeng I don't know, my friend. Someone should tell them. There's also a slightly possibility that `etoolbox` is to blame, not `hyperref`, but who knows?

Comment: Okay. LaTeX always has bugs, if not here, just there.